# Invited friends aren't getting apprequest invitations, Facebook API-SDK

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

Hi I'm sending app requests invitations and my facebook friends aren't getting nothing. I'm using the Facebook API is loading perfectly in my page I can connect , retrieve the basic fb data, email and stream publish ... and right now I'm trying to send invitations from the same page using this code

```
PIGSKIN.inviteFBfriendsToGroup = function () {
    //console.log("invite FB friends");
    FB.ui({
        method: 'apprequests',
        message: 'Invita a tus amigos a unirse al PigSkin Caliente',
        display: "iframe"
    },function (response) {
        console.log("Response", response);
        var friends = response.to;
        if (friends.length > 0) {
            FB.ui({
              method: 'apprequests',
              message: 'Te invito a unirte al PigSkin de Caliente',
              to: friends.join(","),
              link: location.href,
              new_style_message: true
            }, function (response) {
                console.log("Response here  ", response);
            });
        } 
    });
};
```

I'm opening the apprequest dialog to select friends and invite them ,then I confirm the invitation request ..

[image]
[image]

and it responds me this

[image]

the response object seems correct I guess ... but checking with my fb friends they didn't receive any invitation ... is this a facebook issue ? or I'm doing something wrong

Sorry I forgot to post my login:

```
FB.login(function (response) {
 if (response.status === 'connected') {
 PIGSKIN.FBconnect(); //Don't worry about this function ...     
 }
},{scope:"email,publish_stream,publish_actions"});
```

Thanks

Facebook documentation 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

Answer (score 2):

your FB.ui function is working perfectly, i've replicate the documentation example with your FB.ui code and the result was successful... Maybe it's facebook, or maybe the permissions on Caliente's fb-page... can't tell... Good luck.